# What Linux distribution to a server on an old PC

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

I have an old PC with 2G RAM, 30G SATA HDD with a pentium II processor.
I wonder what Linux distro to make my own server ?
This server will be used for: gcc/g++ with vim/emacs

I don't want any GUI or DE, just command line. And I would like access the server just with ssh. So just a minimal install I think.

I looked at: Slax, puppy, gentoo and Arch....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have Fedora's XFCE spin happily running on an EEE 900 with 1.5gb of ram, and a 16gb SSD disk. A bit slow, but fine for casual use. For actual development, though, you will find using g++ and emacs to be excruciatingly slow.

Answer (score 1):

Performance is fine for pretty much every Linux Distro.

If you want to run a server, choose one of the typical server distros.

Debian, Ubuntu LTS, CentOS maybe Open SUSE

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend the ["Ubuntu Minimal CD"](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/14.04/).

It defaults to installing a very minimal setup, with options to bulk install standard packages for different scenarios (LAMP, SSH, Email server, etc) during the installation (you can skip this step if you wish).

After the system is installed, you can use normal apt-get commands to install packages at will to build the system up the way you need.

Once installed, these commands will get you your required software:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install vim-nox
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements Debian or Fedora will probably be your best choices as these distributions will hang on to old hardware support where Arch or Ubuntu may not.

Almost any popular Linux distribution can be a server and will run will be performant on old CPUs and small amounts of ram. Debian, Fedora and Arch make minimal installs quite easy while CentOS and Ubuntu aren't as easy. However some distros such as CentOS can be a preinstalled container that is minimal.

Comment: Do you think the op managed to get his (her) server running as the question was asked 3 years ago?